# How to render express views dynamically

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I'm new to express JS and try to build CMS like this:

1. Users have a page builder, where they can drag-and-drop different components on the page.
2. each component has its own data which also is defined by a user
3. Each component has its own view template

So, I have to check what components have to load, prepare data for each of them, send this data to an appropriate template, render one big HTML and send to the client.

I know, It's too complicated to explain how to build this, but any tutorials, examples, resources would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can accomplish this using the `include` function that most template languages have.  For the example, I'll use `ejs`.  Also, I'm assuming you know how to get the data for user selections to your server.

on your app.js:

```
app.get('/someRoute', function(req, res) {

    var data = //get user data here

    res.render('someTemplate', {data:data});
});
```

someTemplate.ejs:

```
<%- include('header') %> //you should do this on every page

<% if (data == 'foo') { %>
   <%- include('foo', {data:data}) %> //note that you can pass data to templates like this
<% } %>

<% if (data == 'bar') %>
    <%- include('bar') %>
<% } %>

<% include('footer') %>
```

foo.ejs:

```
//some component here
```

If you want to read more, check the [docs](https://ejs.co/).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***Template Engine*** for that purpose because it enables you to use static template files in your application. At run time, the template engine replaces variables in a template file with actual values, and transforms the template into an HTML file sent to the client. This approach makes it easier to design an HTML page.

Some popular template engines that work with Express are **Pug**, **Mustache**, and **EJS**. The Express application generator uses **Jade** as its default, but it also supports several others.

Also check this [link](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html)

Comment: I'm using Template Engines... the issue is that views should be generated dynamically... for example:

Customer chooses to have on one page:

- Gallery
- Feedback form
- Slider

1. check the database and see component list for this page
2. generate data for each component
3. (?) generate layouts and sed back. But as you might see I can't define this 3 components partials in main template hard coded.